# Django view didn't return an HttpResponse object though I added render

Tags: django

The following view method is returning a None and not a HttpResponse object.

```
def upload(request):
    def get(self, request):
        photos_list = Images.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'rango/view.html', {'photos': photos_list},)

    def post(self, request):
        form = ImagesForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}

        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}

        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Even though I am returning a render, why am I getting this?

Comment: Are you using a class-based-view (CBV) ? If yes then `upload` should be a `Class`, not a function. This wont work as in FBV you have to diffrentiate between `post` and `get` method by `if-condition`, checking if `request.method` is POST or GET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function looks like a `class` but you're not using it as a class. the `self` for a class represents the `object` being created. A class, in that case, is not needed, so remove all `self`

```
def upload(request):
    photos_list = Images.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST'
        form = ImagesForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 
                    'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)
    return render(request, 'rango/view.html', {'photos': photos_list},)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `upload()` is a function based view, not a class based view. And it's never calling nested `get` or `post` methods in your code.

You should rewrite it like this to make it work:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}

        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}

        return JsonResponse(data)
    else:
        photos_list = Images.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'rango/view.html', {'photos': photos_list},)
```